# chatGPTのモデル"davinci"では正確に返答されないのでしょうか。

Tags: python, line, chatgpt

公式LINEで質問したことをwebhookを介してchatGPTが回答してくれるチャットボットを作成しています。
現状、メッセージを受信して自動返信することはできるのですが、受信したメッセージに対して全く見当違いな返信をします。下記のコードが受信したメッセージをchatGPTで処理し、LINEに送信するコードです。
これは、モデルが"davinci"だからなのでしょうか、それともコードが悪いのでしょうか。ご教授お願いします。
※情報不足なところがあればご指摘お願いします。

```
#メッセージを受け取った後にどんな処理を行うかを記述
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=TextMessage)
def handle_message(event):
    prompt =event.message.text

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="davinci",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=256,
    )
    messages = response.choices[0].text.strip()

    print(messages)

    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        TextSendMessage(text=messages))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これだと **"続けて相手が言いそうなこと"** もしくは **"その続きに書いてありそうなこと"** を生成するだけです。

チャットをさせたいなら、プロンプトとパラメータは公式exampleのチャットの例
https://platform.openai.com/examples/default-friend-chat
に倣って

```
prompt = f'You: {event.message.text}\nFriend:'
response = openai.Completion.create(
    model='davinci',
    prompt=prompt,
    stop='You: ',
    max_tokens=60,
    temperature=0.5,
    frequency_penalty=0.5,
)
```

とか指定するといいでしょう。Davinciモデルでも十分と思います。

（ボットに組み込む前に短いコードでどんどん試した方がいいですよ。質問もしやすいですし）

---

できれば過去のやりとりも渡すのがいいと思います。次のチャレンジにはなるでしょうが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。コード参考にさせてもらったら上手くいきました！公式の方見ながら進めていくことにします。ありがとうございました。